# Get row count to Laravel blade View

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get count of total users registered on the system to my dashboard.
Can I get users row count of users table  `Laravel` View Directly ?

```
<div class="info-box-content">
     <span class="info-box-text">Users</span>
     <span class="info-box-number">
          **Users Count**   
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show some code of view file

Comment: take a look on the documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this. Is is going to be shown on one page or multiple pages using the same component?

Comment: Dear Ross , Its going to show on a single page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try,

```
$userCount = Users::count();
```

if you want users to be filtered the use with where clause

```
$userCount = Users::where('your_condition')->count();
```

If your passing data to blade then,It depends how you're passing to blade

```
//From your controller
$usersData = Users::all();

//In your blade
@if(count($usersData) > 0 )

@endif

//OR
@if($usersData->count() > 0 )

@endif


<div class="info-box-content">
     <span class="info-box-text">Users</span>
     <span class="info-box-number">
         // {{ count($usersData) }}
         // OR
         // {{ $usersData->count() }}
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to get count directly to laravel view. means without accessing a controller or model